# Do (H2) database passwords protect when attacker has access to local files?

Tags: database, h2

This is with reference to all database servers, and in particular to H2. Do database passwords protect data when having physical access to the media?

I think they are only used to protect remote access via the server and not if the attacker has local access. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 supports [file encryption](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#file_encryption) which does protect you if the attacker can read the files. For version 1.4.x, when using [the MVStore](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#encryption), the password is hashed with [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), and the [XTS-AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29) algorithm is used. This is the same as modern disk, hardware, or file system encryption [typically](http://www.jetico.com/web_help/bcve3_enterprise/html/03_standards/03_mode.htm) [works](http://www.kingston.com/en/usb/encrypted_security/xts_encryption).